# vim remote editing: ftpplugin or remote vim over ssh

Tags: linux, vim

I'm new to vim. And am little confused about editing remote files. It has built-in ftp plugin and also is installed on remote server. Which way should I go with ? 
I have noticed that with ftpplugin saving and exploring  is slower but editing and navigating is obviously faster. But I dont know which way is better in total.

(If answer is to use local vim then should I mount remote folder or use ftpplugin?)

Comment: What kind of editing are you doing remotely? Why don't you use a VCS or even a GUI FTP client?

Comment: I'm doing php,html,js work. An external ftp app would slow me down.(save-switch other app-upload etc) A vcs isn't necessary because most of the time i'm only one working there.

Comment: Well, there's no absolute "better" way. You must try all the options and see which one is the best *for you*.

Answer (score 1):

- If I would just change a single file, and then I am done with my work. I would go: `vim scp://...`  (with ssh key authentication)
- If I need to change many files, and then do some other stuff on that server. e.g. file operation(cp, mv...) or some server management (apache/jboss/.. start, restart...) I would ssh into the server.
- If I need to do some programming on a remote server directly (rarely happened), I would ssh in to the server as well.
- If a mount is anyway there on your local machine, then why not just use it?

P.S. maybe irrelevant to your question, but I would mention that if you ssh into remote server and work, screen/tmux would help you a lot!

Good luck.

Comment: I though mounting might cause performance loss on local system an was dangerous. e.g if accidentally  type rm -r /mnt/* , does this delete remote folder? or does du -s calculate remote files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's personal preference. Vim over ssh has always worked fine for me, though it would probably not be a good idea over a high latency connection, such as a satellite link, or crappy wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up mounting my external servers and then using vim locally. Yes, there is a slight lag when saving but really, not that slow. Also, having all of my bindings, plugins and themes available really made the choice obvious.

Comment: the remote vim can have your own bindings, plugins themes as well. if the .vimrc you meant is `~/.vimrc`

Comment: true! i should add i abandoned ftp inside of vim because it was so slow and so my actual options were to ssh into a remote server and run vim from there or local. good point Kent.